# Django homepage on port 8000 not answer

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

i uploaded a docker-compose with Django and Mysql, and everythings looks okay. `docker container ls` show both containers running, but Django homepage on port 8000 not answer. I got another one docker-compose with postgres and that works well. What can possibly going on?

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on: 
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
     - '3306:3306'
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'djangomysql'
      MYSQL_USER: 'wendel'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'wendel12'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'wendel12'
```

Comment: What does `docker logs` on the container show?

Comment: show the following message: web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)"). the link contains all exception https://gist.github.com/wendelrios/f4f65ebfe21f76de93dde9411fd75afd

Comment: Have you tried restarting the `web` container after the `db` has started? You could get this error if the `web` container is trying to set up a connection to the database while the `db` container is still starting. Try running `docker-compose restart web`

Comment: @timsmelik it worked man! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the port for django

```
command: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8032
```

and go to file setting.py add

---

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: it didnt work man... i keep facing this problem. why you recommend set port to 8032? I dont understand if the same settings works for postgres why it doesnt work for mysql...

Comment: Because the port on mysql works on default port 80, either change the port for mysql or try on port 80

Comment: mysql port on 80? isnt 3306?

Comment: Apache  Port 80 in use by xamp
mysql port 3306 in xamp 
change port 3306 to 3307
1-Close XAMPP Server

2-Open file C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini (C: is the default XAMPP Installation)

3-Replace the port number 3306 with 3307
try this:

This is in case you are using it xampp

Comment: man i'm not using xamp... i'm doing that through docker-compose, and i'm on mac os... but thanks for your help

Comment: No problem!.. Welcome